# How do I import my 12 Breadwallet seed words into Electrum?

Tags: wallet, electrum, seed, wallet-import, breadwallet

When I write them into Electrum during the restore from seed box, the Next button is disabled.

[image: words shown are for illustrative purposes only]

Answer (score 1):

Breadwallet uses BIP 39, but Electrum no longer does. However, Electrum does have a compatibility option for BIP 39 seeds. Just click the "Options" button and check the box labeled "BIP 39 Seed".

Comment: Also specify m/0' in derivation path on the next screen

Answer (score 0):

Breadwallet uses BIP39, which Electrum's seeds are is not compatible with.

(There are some people online saying it's possible to make it work, but I can't figure it out.)

As an alternative, MultiBit is compatible with BIP39.

[Here's a spreadsheet](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=584F122BA17116EE!313&app=Excel), written by Christopher Gurnee, showing a list of wallets, and whether those wallets are compatible with BIP39.

Comment: Your sheet line 11 says Electrum _is_ BIP39. I have v2.8.2. Actually I'm trying to get away from MultibitHD and wanted to verify that I could access my Breadwallet before I wipe it and try to import MultibitHD. Electrum won't import MultibitHD seeds either. I see a lot of red/incompatibles so I guess it's normal that nothing works. Was worried I picked the wrong wallet.

Comment: It does say that, but I can't get it working, so I didn't want to assert it worked.

Comment: same question here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/6btevz/how_do_i_import_my_12_breadwallet_seed_words_into/?st=j2u3d29m&sh=d18c92f1