# Cannot recover wallet from 12 word BIP 39 seed generated by Bread Wallet on iOS

Tags: client, bip32-hd-wallets

I still have access to my Bread Wallet on iOS, but I'm trying to test my setup and make sure that I can recover my wallet if for some reason Bread wallet didn't work or if I simply wanted to change wallet providers without having to send my BTC to a new address.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to successfully "recover" my wallet using the 12-word seed that Bread Wallet generated. I've tried Electrum on macOS, Mycelium on iOS and Copay on iOS. I'm beginning to think that I'm misunderstanding something about the wallet recovery process.

My assumption is that I should be able to use that 12-word seed on any BIP 32 supported wallet, which would then regenerate the private keys and "recover" the UTXO that belongs to key hierarchy.

It definitely seems like bread supports BIP 32 according to their docs [here](https://github.com/breadwallet/breadwallet-core/wiki)

Does anyone know what I need to do to recover my wallet using my 12-word seed phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electrum doesn't support BIP39 (by default) as far as i know, so you will need to use another wallet.

You could try and use an older version of Electrum, then enable BIP39 seeds, and see if that works.

See https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=584F122BA17116EE!313&app=Excel for wallets that DO support BIP39 seeds.

But then again, you said you tried Mycelium aswell, which might use BIP44 by default..?

Or, you choose for a "New" wallet when first booting up Mycelium, instead of the "Recovering" option.

You need to click the recovering/restore from backup option and fill in your seed, otherwise it won't work. Don't ask me why.

If you currently installed mycelium, you should delete all of it's apdate and reinstall it.

Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/53461/61384

Comment: Thanks for the link to that spreadsheet, that looks exactly like what I was looking for!